# Белый фон при нажатии на ссылку с телефона

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Как исправить белый фон при нажатии на ссылку с телефона?

```
div class="memories__button">
            <a
              href="#"
              target="_blank"
              class="button-memories"
              >Оставить воспоминания</a
            >
          </div>


  .memories__button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
  margin: 8px 0 0 0;
  }

.button-memories {
display: flex;
text-align: center;
align-items: center;
max-height: 36px;
background: #222223;
box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px #7882fb;
border: 1px solid;
border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #84a4ff, #1124cd) 1;
font-family: "Montserrat";
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 122%;
letter-spacing: 0.04em;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 11px 21px;
  }

 .button-memories:focus {
  background: #233373;
  }

  .button-memories:hover {
   background: #17214b;
   }

  .button-memories:active {
  background: #4d60af;
  }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может у вас где-то в css прописано свойство для нажатой ссылки?

Comment: Да, забыла прописать. .button-memories:focus {
  background: #233373;
}
.button-memories:hover {
  background: #17214b;
}

.button-memories:active {
  background: #4d60af;
}

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .memories__button {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   margin: 8px 0 0 0;
 }

 .button-memories {
   display: flex;
   text-align: center;
   align-items: center;
   max-height: 36px;
   background: #222223;
   box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px #7882fb;
   border: 1px solid;
   border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #84a4ff, #1124cd) 1;
   font-family: "Montserrat";
   font-weight: 400;
   font-size: 12px;
   line-height: 122%;
   letter-spacing: 0.04em;
   color: #ffffff;
   padding: 11px 21px;
 }

 .button-memories:focus {
   background: #233373;
 }

 .button-memories:hover {
   background: #17214b;
 }

 .button-memories:active {
   background: #4d60af;
 }
```

```html
<div class="memories__button">
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="button-memories">Оставить воспоминания</a>
</div>
```

Оно или отнаследывает background-color от родителя .team__text либо это не ссылка, поскольку, по нажатию  на ссылке должен происходить редирект на указаную страницу и вы вообще фона видеть не должны

Comment: Да, ошиблась. Не то скопировала. Код исправила.

Comment: Это точно ссылка ? Или просто это некий декор элемент который идет с параметром `event.preventDefault();` Просто если там намешан JS то может быть 100500 причин как испортить дефолтную работу ссылки. Попробуйти заменить тег `<a>` скажем на `<span>` уйдет ли проблема.

Comment: Точно ссылка. Там нет JS

Comment: Тогда это от наследование стилей ссылки или классов оборачиваемого элемента. Судя по прикремленному рисунку там ещё и скругление `border-radius` добавляеться. Так, что тут можно будет понять только если выложите куда-то код проекта... так не понять. Проверил предложеный код на своем мобильном, у меня всё ок.

Comment: https://github.com/AnnaMikula03/Memory-board.git вот полный код проекта

Comment: закинул к себе на тестовый сервер, опробовал на Андроид мобильном у меня ссылка белой не становиться ни как. Может что-то закешировалось... Попробуй убрать `target="_blank"` или сбросить кеш.